# Android lighten colors by 20-30% in colors.xml

Tags: android

I have many colours stored in my colors.xml To lighten them I simply made them more transparent by adding #E6 before the hex code which worked perfectly. However when using bottom sheets when the sheet expands, because the colour is slightly transparent I can see content under the bottom sheet which makes the content inside the bototm sheet hard to read.

Is there a simply way to edit the hex codes for all my colors to make them 20-30% lighter without using transparency

```
 <color name="fine">#1DE9B6</color>
 <color name="fine_toolbar">#E61DE9B6</color>
```

Comment: There's no way to edit resources like you're looking for, they're designed to be constant at runtime. You may just have to add a couple extra colors that you use for the bottom sheet, different from the rest

Comment: Im happy to add new colours I mean is there s simple way to edit the hex code to make it lighter?

Comment: Use [this](https://www.hexcolortool.com/#51c874) tool. It has a lighten and a darken button, both of which will provide you with respective variations of the given hex code color

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool at this link:

https://www.hexcolortool.com/#51c874

provided by Amin answered the question and provided the functionality I required.